# Ionic 6 PWA Capacitor 3 Camera plugin getPhoto method open camera like native camera view

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

Does anyone know how to open native fullscreen camera (2nd image) in an Ionic PWA on mobile phones directly from getPhotos() method, instead of opening camera view showing in browser w/ url bar still showing (3rd image)? 1st image allows us to select take photo which will open native fullscreen camera.

ImageOption attribute presentationStyle 'fullscreen' or 'popover' does not seem to have any affect on camera presentation in mobile PWA.

[image: from 1st image tapping photos icon allows opening camera again]

[image: fullscreen native camera view resulting from 2nd image]

[image: iOS PWA Capacitor camera view opened by getPhotos() method]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `webUseInput` option set to true or uninstall pwa-elements package